# How can I generate a username in an existing table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table named "users" consisting with columns: studentid and password. I wanted to add a new column, that would automatically generate a username from an another table which all the student information is found. Supposedly, I would like a new column for the users that has a username "lastname.firstname", since its already an existing database doing it manually takes a lot of time. I'm wondering if their is an easy way.

Comment: Something like insert into .... select first+last from ... is the statement you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add username column to users table and execute query like this.

```
UPDATE users u
SET username = (SELECT first_name || '.' || last_name 
               FROM student s 
               WHERE u.userid = s.userid)
```

Comment: Don't forget to fix the duplicates when finished.